# How to measure the current inter-VLAN routing throughput / utilization of Cisco L3 switches?

Tags: throughput, utilization

How can I determine the utilization of inter-VLAN routing throughput for Cisco Catalyst L3 switches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are out of luck. L3 switches (well, the low level ones you are considering) do not have the ability to keep vlan counters. What you see in the interface is CPU bound traffic, not real traffic. That will also apply to MIB counters.

If you are willing to spare a couple of ports you could funnel the traffic through a cable and then have one vlan traffic counters. That will not scale though. Time to upgrade to a Nexus ? :) Or an ASR1k ?

Comment: Well, this kind of ruining my day ;) I am only interested in those numbers because the client moving core routing from Cisco to Check Point for network segmentation and inline IPS/AV/AB/URLF and App control.  Current switches will be replaced with updated versions, but I think they have decided to stick with Catalysts (9500 I think), but those will be predominantly responsible for L2 and, may be, site-to-site routing on both, inside and outside of the firewall cluster.

Comment: I've never had one of these on my hands, so I have no experience with the kind of features on their ASICs. I guess it would be try and see if it works. But I know for sure it does not on 3560s, 3750s and the like.

Answer (score 0):

`show interface` will give you utilization on a Cisco switch.

Comment: Show interface, when executed against VLAN interface will result in: switch# show interface vlan 10
Vlan10 is up, line protocol is up
Hardware is EtherSVI, address is 0005.9b78.6e7c
MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
 
switch#  Which is not helpful. I need a utilization values, i.e. min, max, avarage on all L3 VLAN to VLAN communication taking place on the switch. I do not mind polling SNMP, if need be, but am not sure what to look for.

Comment: I have used `show interface` on Vlans on many Cisco Catalyst switches, and they always have Utilization. What is the Model of your Cisco Switch?

Comment: 2950, 3650 and 4510. Again, I am not interested in seeing utilization per VLAN, but the utiliza.tion of the L3 traffic routed between VLANs on the same switch or stack.

Comment: There should be 5 minute input and output rate, plus load on the output for Utilization.

Comment: How would you differentiate between min/max values of all the interfaces that belong to the VLAN which parameters you are viewing and the traffic routed to other VLANs?

Comment: You will need to better describe what you are looking for.

Comment: I need to replace existing Cisco routing switch with clustered firewall and IPS solution. In order to size this solution properly, I have to determine how much traffic is being routed between VLANs on the switches. Not how much traffic traversing each VLAN or its constituent ports, but total amount of traffic between different subnets residing on individual VLANs.

Comment: To summarize; you are looking for historical data. You can try to get third party solution, like PRTG to monitor the traffic over a period of time. It will also give you minimum and maximum traffic. On high end Cisco Layer 3 devices, there is a `show interface history` command that gives you more historical details, but not on lower end switches.

Comment: Regardless of what I will end-up using to graph the data, prtg, mrtg, nagios, solarwinds, etc., I need to know what probes to configure for this information to be accurate.

Comment: The closest I've come so far is the IPv4 statistic counters on SVIs, but those are not available across all the switches I need to assess, just on 4510.

Comment: All you are going to get is what you see with 'show interface' for the VLAN interface on low end switches. If you need more details, you will need to deploy a high end switch or external router with Netflow support.

Comment: Well, therein lies a problem. I will be replacing the existing switches with firewalls. There is no compelling reason to replace them with higher end switches just to measure the performance and to swap them out :)

Comment: That would be a decision that only you can make and justify. We can only provide you with the solution that is available with given hardware and software.